# ForeignKey/OneToOneField referencing a set of unique_together fields?

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys

I would like to add some metadata to a certain object in my Django models. Normally this would be a good situation for a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) or even [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), but in my case there's an additional special requirement:

Due to the way data is synchronized in the overall system, the database storage for the actual "target" objects occasionally get re-created. That is, from time to time all the object rows get deleted and new ones are created in their place. But I need the metadata to persist.

Besides its implicit primary key, each object also has a textual slug field that uniquely identifies it — but **only** within a single container. This slug is stable across the data being re-created, as is the container itself. So I'd like to use a combination of an object's slug and its container to associate my metadata, rather than the database primary key for the object.

I found the `to_field` option on the `ForeignKey` model field, but if I set for example `to_field='id_in_container'` it complains since the `id_in_container` field is not unique on its own, only together with the `container` field.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Object(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    id_in_container = models.SlugField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('container', 'id_in_container')

# BUG: this won't actually work, `to_field` can't take a tuple!
DESIRED_COMBO = ('container','id_in_container')

class ObjectMetadata(models.model):
    object = models. OneToOneField(Object, to_field=DESIRED_COMBO)
    # … additional fields …
```

That is, have a `OneToOneField` or `ForeignKey` that targets multiple columns of a target model, when those columns are `unique_together`?

I suppose I can implement some manual helpers, perhaps like this:

```
class ObjectMetadata(models.model):
    object_container = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    object_slug = models.SlugField()
    # … additional fields …

    @classmethod
    def get_for_object(cls, obj):
        return cls.objects.get(object_container=obj.container, object_slug=obj.id_in_container)
```

…but I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate way to model this.

Comment: I think your own proposed solution with the helper is most appropriate in this scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, but take a look at [GFK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

Comment: Django doesn't support composite foreign keys. This feature has proven quite difficult to implement, so even though many have tried, it has never been merged into Django. You'll have to fake the join like you do in your `get_for_object` method.